# Expandable List view list Appasres according select the number items in number picker

Tags: android

Here i have  number picker i want to select the number in number picker then in expandable list view data will be show according the selected number in number picker. please help me out.`[When i select the number 1 then child 1 appears only and when i select the number 2 in number picker then child 1 and child 2 only Display on screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ev78E.jpg) 
    **Here my MainJava Class**
    package com.example.elite_android.explistview1;

```
import android.content.ClipData;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import android.widget.ExpandableListAdapter;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.NumberPicker;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.NumberPicker;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ExpandableListView expandableListView;

    private ExpandableListAdapter mAdapter;
    ExpandableListView expand;
    NumberPicker numberPicker;

        @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);




        String [] numbers = new String[10];
        for (int count = 0; count < 10; count++)
            numbers[count] = String.valueOf(count);

        numberPicker = (NumberPicker) findViewById(R.id.main_number_picker);
        numberPicker.setMaxValue(numbers.length);
        numberPicker.setMinValue(1);
        numberPicker.setDisplayedValues(numbers);

        numberPicker.setOnValueChangedListener(new NumberPicker.OnValueChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onValueChange(NumberPicker picker, int oldVal, int newVal) {

            }
        });


        expandableListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.exp_Listview);

        List<String> headerItems = new ArrayList<String>();
        headerItems.add("Child 1");
        headerItems.add("Child 2");
        headerItems.add("Child 3");

        ArrayList childDetails = new ArrayList();
        childDetails.add("Name");
        childDetails.add("Age");
        childDetails.add("Gender");

        HashMap<String, List<String>> childList = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
        childList.put(headerItems.get(0), childDetails);
        childList.put(headerItems.get(1), childDetails);
        childList.put(headerItems.get(2), childDetails);

        mAdapter = new MyAdapter(this, headerItems, childList);
        expandableListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    };



        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
            return true;
        }
    }

`
**and here my Adapter class**

    package com.example.elite_android.explistview1;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseExpandableListAdapter;
import android.widget.NumberPicker;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by ELITE-ANDROID on 28-02-2017.
 */
// this is provides all needs methods  implementing an Expandable List VIew

public class MyAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

    // We need some Variables here so therer are some Variables here

     private List<String> header_titles;                     // This is for Representing the HeadLine
     private HashMap<String, List<String>> child_titles;     //  defin the HashMap for the child item how to Represent the Parent Handing so Hash Map, need some Variables
    private Context ctx;
    private NumberPicker numberPicker;


    //for  initalized for all Variables we need some Constructor
    public MyAdapter(Context context,List<String>header_titles,HashMap<String,List<String>>child_titles) {

        this.ctx = context;
        this.child_titles = child_titles;
        this.header_titles = header_titles;
    }


    @Override
    // From this Override  method How to Return how many elements are the Group count like parent
    public int getGroupCount()
    {
        return header_titles.size();
    }


    @Override
    //here  the number of child items are in each heading. There are three Heading - PAtien Name ,Age, Gender
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {

//        Log.d("xxx", )
        return child_titles.get(header_titles.get(groupPosition)).size(); //how to Return the size of HashMap

//        return child_titles.get(header_titles.get(groupPosition)).size();
    }


    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition)
    {
        return header_titles.get(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    // here how to retuen child items on the particular headings and Positions.
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return child_titles.get(header_titles.get(groupPosition)).get(childPosition);
  }


    @Override

    //return the groupo position
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return childPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return false;
    }


    @Override
    // Here return the Group View
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {

//        header_titles = new ArrayList<String>();
//        header_titles.add("List 1");

        // Here how to get the Heading Title here Decalered String Variables, now how to get title of heading from getGroup methods so simple call Backed Methods.
        String title = (String)this.getGroup(groupPosition);
        if (convertView == null)
        {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)this.ctx.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.prent,null);
        }

        TextView textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.heading_item);
        textView.setText(title);     //  for Heading bold style
        textView.setText(title);     // for set the title

        return convertView;
    }


    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild,  View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        String title = (String) this.getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) ctx.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.child, null);
        }

        TextView sequence = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.sequence);
        //sequence.setText();
        //sequence.setText(detailInfo.getSequence().trim() + ") ");
        TextView childItem = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.child_item);
        childItem.setText(title);

        return convertView;
    }



    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    package com.example.elite_android.explistview1;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import android.widget.ExpandableListAdapter;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.NumberPicker;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.NumberPicker;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ExpandableListView expandableListView;

    private MyAdapter mAdapter;
    ExpandableListView expand;
    NumberPicker numberPicker;

    private List<String> headerItems;
    private ArrayList childDetails;
    private HashMap<String, List<String>> childList;
    private Context ctx;

    EditText editText1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

//        get reference to the EditText
        editText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.child_item);
//        //set the onFocusChange listener
//        // editText1.setOnFocusChangeListener(editText1.getOnFocusChangeListener());
//
////        //get reference to EditText
////        editText2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.sequence);
////        // set the on focusChange listner
////        editText2.setOnFocusChangeListener(editText2.getOnFocusChangeListener());
//
//        //Generate list View from ArrayList;
//
//
//        EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.child_item);
//        editText.requestFocus();
//        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
//        imm.showSoftInput(editText, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
//
//
////        editText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
//        //          @Override
//        //        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
//        //          //editText.setOnFocusChangeListener();
//        //        return;
//        //  }
//        //});
//

        String[] numbers = new String[10];
        for (int count = 0; count < 10; count++)
            numbers[count] = String.valueOf(count);

        numberPicker = (NumberPicker) findViewById(R.id.main_number_picker);
        numberPicker.setMaxValue(numbers.length);
        numberPicker.setMinValue(1);
        numberPicker.setDisplayedValues(numbers);

        numberPicker.setOnValueChangedListener(new NumberPicker.OnValueChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onValueChange(NumberPicker picker, int oldVal, int newVal) {
                generateListItems(newVal);
                loadRecycleView();


            }
        });
    }

    private void generateListItems(int childCount) {
        if (headerItems != null)
            headerItems.clear();
        else
            headerItems = new ArrayList<>();

        if (childList != null)
            childList.clear();
        else
            childList = new HashMap();

        if (childDetails == null) {
            childDetails = new ArrayList();
            childDetails.add("Name");
            childDetails.add("Age");
            childDetails.add("Gender");
        }

        // Put header items
        for (int count = 0; count < childCount; count++) {
            headerItems.add(" Parent " + count);
            childList.put(headerItems.get(count), childDetails);
        }
    }

    private void loadRecycleView() {
        if (expandableListView == null) {
            expandableListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.exp_Listview);
            mAdapter = new MyAdapter(this, headerItems, childList);
            expandableListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        } else {
            expandableListView.invalidate();
            mAdapter.setHeaderData(headerItems);
            mAdapter.setListData(childList);
            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

}


**Adapter class**


    package com.example.elite_android.explistview1;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.widget.BaseExpandableListAdapter;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView;
import android.widget.NumberPicker;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.EditText;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by ELITE-ANDROID on 28-02-2017.
 */
// this is provides all needs methods  implementing an Expandable List VIew

public class MyAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

    // We need some Variables here so therer are some Variables here


    private List<String> header_titles;                     // This is for Representing the HeadLine(Array list)
    private HashMap<String, List<String>> child_titles;     //  defin the HashMap for the child item how to Represent the Parent Handing so Hash Map, need some Variables
    private Context ctx;
    private NumberPicker numberPicker;
    EditText editText;
    private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;

    //for  initalized for all Variables we need some Constructor
    public MyAdapter(Context context, List<String> header_titles, HashMap<String, List<String>> child_titles) {

        super();
        this.ctx = context;
        this.child_titles = child_titles;
        this.header_titles = header_titles;


    }

    public void refreshHeader_titles(List<String> events) {
        this.header_titles.clear();
        this.header_titles.addAll(header_titles);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    ;


    @Override
    // From this Override  method How to Return how many elements are the Group count like parent
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return header_titles.size();
    }


    @Override
    //here  the number of child items are in each heading. There are three Heading - PAtien Name ,Age, Gender
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {

//        Log.d("xxx", )
        return child_titles.get(header_titles.get(groupPosition)).size(); //how to Return the size of HashMap

    }


    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return header_titles.get(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    // here how to retuen child items on the particular headings and Positions.
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return child_titles.get(header_titles.get(groupPosition)).get(childPosition);
    }

    @Override
    //return the groupo position
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return childPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return false;
    }


    @Override
    // Here return the Group View
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        // Here how to get the Heading Title here Decalered String Variables, now how to get title of heading from getGroup methods so simple call Backed Methods.
        String title = (String) this.getGroup(groupPosition);
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.ctx.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.prent, null);
        }
        TextView textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.heading_item);
        textView.setText(title);     //  for Heading bold style ,title
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        String title = (String) this.getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) ctx.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.child, null);
        }

        String cellData = child_titles.get(header_titles.get(groupPosition)).get(childPosition);

        EditText childItem = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.child_item);
        childItem.setHint(cellData);

        childItem.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                Log.d("xxxx", "Has focus " + hasFocus);
                if (hasFocus) {

                } else {

                }

                return;
            }
        });

        return convertView;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return true;
    }

    public void setListData(HashMap<String, List<String>> lData) {
        child_titles = lData;
    }

    public void setHeaderData(List<String> hData) {
        header_titles = hData;
    }
}
```